# Maven server configuration in my laptop

Tags: maven

I have a laptop which needs to be configure as Maven central repository. So that everyone can download new libraries from the server along with the source code.

Is there any such configuration available for Maven.?

Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: You would probably move the repo to a 'server' instead of a laptop. Always wired and always accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since a maven repo is mainly a defined file structure you have several options to do that.

One would be to locally install a nexus (or artifactory) server. both is fairly straight forward. This has a lot of advantages when it comes to remote repository administration.

Or you create a local HTTP Server and just put your stuff into an accessible directory.

Every developer that needs to access your notebook should then modify the settings.xml in his home directory and add is as mirror. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html for details.